# Analyzing community builder database

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-community-builder

My server is Joomla 2.5, the version of CB is 1.8.1 and it runs on a MySQL database.

I would like to analyze the data in my database and create simple reports, for example: a list of all email addresses of all subscribers in a given period in time.

Is the right tool for this available in CB, in Joomla as an extension or should I go for a separate tool to dive into the database directly?

I searched in the CB site for reporting but didn't find a plugin for it, did find some 'advanced search' extensions for Joomla but they do not support reports as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Community Builder won't do this on it's own.

The easiest and quickest way to achieve this is to use an extension like ChronoForms and/or ChronoConnectivity which can help retrieve and display the required data from one or more tables.

ChronoForms: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms/1508
ChronoConnectivity: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/directory/5661

These extensions make it easy to restrict a report to a particular group etc without having to write code.

There are plenty of examples in the chronoengine.com FAQs and the forum if you need help.

Answer (score 2):

I had to write custom components for this kind of requirements a few times, if you are familiar with Joomla coding I strongly suggest this approach it will be the most effective unless you need strong business intelligence, in which case you'd better switch to a bi tool.

The difference is: if you can pull all the data you need with just a few simple queries, write them yourself; if you need to analyze data, use a proper tool.

If you however are not a developer you might get away with a reporting tool, or a versatile CCK for Joomla.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the original question is not valide anymore, about an year later, but now there is a component that does what you need if you use ”registerDate” field as search criteria. The name of the component is JEmbedAll and you can find more information about that here: http://www.goldengravel.eu/jembedall-manual#.VVph_bvyNC0